# What does the word expression mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

This is a question from OkCupid, a dating app:

> If you had to name your greatest motivation in life thus far, what
>   would it be?

There are 4 options: Love, Knowledge, Wealth, Expression.

---

What does **expression** mean here?

Comment: This is an off-topic cross post of the identical question at [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/481699/what-does-the-word-expression-mean-here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Expression** - *noun* - The action of making known one's thoughts or feelings.

**Source**: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/expression

**Cultural Note**: When people are dating, they are really looking for a compatible partner short term or long term. They may look into the greatest motivation in life at this moment. They may want a partner who is motivated by love. Love guides the person's behaviors. They may want a partner who is motivated by knowledge. Pursuing knowledge is important for the person. They may want a partner who is motivated by wealth. Wealth is important for the person. They may want a partner who is motivated by expression. Sharing thoughts and feelings is important for the person.

A person who chooses "expression" may say this:

> I am motivated by expression in everything I do. I want to be able to share my thoughts and feelings with my future partner. Our relationship together should be dependent on communication. The more we communicate, the deeper our friendship will be, and the more we trust each other.